# $variable with site_url codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to know if it is possible to get a $variable id mixed in with the codeigniter.

Currently just shows `http://localhost/codeigniter/codeigniter-cms/0`

I just need it to display `http://localhost/codeigniter/codeigniter-cms/admin/setting` with id hidden and still access this controller.

But If create new website it has different ID so different settings.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
$data['websites'][] = array(
'website_id' => $result->website_id,
'name' => $result->name,
'url' => $result->url,
'edit'     => site_url('admin/setting') . $result->website_id
);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php if ($websites) { ?>
<?php foreach($websites as $website) { ?>
<tr>
<td class="text-center"><?php if (in_array($website['website_id'], $selected)) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $website['website_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $website['website_id']; ?>" />
<?php } ?></td>
<td><?php echo $website['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $website['url'];?> </td>
<td class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $website['website_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit Website</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr>
<td class="text-center" colspan="4">NO RESULTS</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you require the id be hidden? (you can obfuscate it), you can send id in POST and save it in session but I would stick with old fashion GET requests with id in them. Also take a look at this route 

`$route['admin/setting/(:num)'] = "";`

Comment: Use a POST form. do not expose the id unless its public.

Comment: POST is also public:)

Comment: It is just when I create a new website/store profile It should still send me to admin/setting but if it has a website/store has a new id it should let me add separate info to db that's why i put row id in href.

Answer (score 0):

I can view link now  changed edit on controller and made on model result_array instead of result. link working fine.

```
'edit' => site_url('admin/setting', $result['website_id'])
```

controller updated

```
$results = $this->model_website->getWebsites();

foreach ($results as $result) {
$data['websites'][] = array(
'website_id' => $result['website_id'],
'name' => $result['name'],
'url' => $result['url'],
'edit'     => site_url('admin/setting', $result['website_id'])
);
}
```

model updated

```
function getWebsites() {
        $this->db->order_by('url', 'asc');

        $query = $this->db->get('website');

      if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        return $query->result_array();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }
```